# How to prevent overrunning of y -axis tick labels in matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

[image: 1]

Hi everyone i am trying to plot a graph from a csv file which includes many unique values specially for y axis(close to 500 values).When graph is plotted y axis tick labels are over running each other and i want each values to be present on y-axis .I dont want to skip values. Can anyone suggest me how can i make my graph having all these 500 values on y-axis read neatly.

```
 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    #plt.figure(figsize=(800/my_dpi, 800/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.00, 5.50]
    plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
    space = 3
    dash_len = 3
    ax.set_facecolor("yellow")
    ax.plot(sorted(failed_it),failed_p,color='r',linestyle='dashed',dashes=(dash_len, 
    space),alpha=0.7, linewidth = 1,marker='s', markerfacecolor='red', markersize=4)
    ax.plot(sorted(passed_it),passed_p,color='g',linestyle='dashed',dashes=(dash_len, 
    space),alpha=0.7, linewidth = 1,marker='d', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=4)
    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
    plt.xlabel("Iteration_Rate",fontweight="bold",fontsize=9)
    plt.ylabel("Trigger_Port,VLAN",fontweight="bold")
    plt.title("Platform="+str(keyss[3])+",Build="+ str(list1_8112[0][1])+",Trigger- 
    SystemRestart",fontweight="bold")
    size = fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi
    print(size)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,6,1))
    ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.07, -0.025)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(100))
`   plt.yticks(port_VLAN_8112,ha='right',fontsize=8)
    plt.xticks(it_rate_8112[::20],ha='right',fontsize=8)
    plt.margins(0)
    ax.grid('on')
    plt.show()
    fig = plt.figure()
```

Comment: You can try using functions `xlim` and `ylim` to place limits on the X and Y axis respectively. [See for more examples](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for changing the ticks frequency.
You can easily do that by calling

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(x)+1, 5))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, max(y), 2))
```

You can see great examples here: [Change Tick Frequency in Matplotlib](https://stackabuse.com/change-tick-frequency-in-matplotlib/#:%7E:text=Setting%20Figure%2DLevel,the%20Y%2Daxis%3A)

Comment: It is not working instead it didnt use all the y-axis and made all the ticks more clustered   .Can you please look into the image link in the description and you know my y-axis values are in the form of 2_1011 which is derived as a single list from csv file as a combination of two columns values.THanks for your help in advance